# Raspberry 3 to tether internet to the ETH port from the wi-fi

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, ethernet, bridge

I would like to use the raspberry to bridge the WI-FI network and the ETH0 port and then connect a router to create my personal network with internet access (if possible DHCP on the router) accessible via WI-FI as well for the other ETH port (ETH-2, ETH-3, ETH-4).

Can you please help me with the set-up ?

[image]

I did try to use dnsmasq but I did not succeed :(

Comment: We have [several "catch-all" Q&A that deal with networking questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=network&searchOn=3). Please delete this question until after you have perused those. If you don't find an answer in those Q&A, a comment to the author of the answer may be productive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it already has answers.

Comment: @Seamus I did not find it ! Do you have the link ?

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong?